# R BiCopKDE cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only

Tags: r

My dataset consists of stock prices. My final goal is to fit for practice a copula to two stocks.
I've transformed my data to a [0,1] scale and would like to plot the bivariate density with BiCopKDE.

However, although I tried to detect possible non-finite values, I still get the same error message "cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only". I reduced my dataset to 16 rows in order to understand the reason, but it didn't help.

The code:

```
DFM.roh <- read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\Simon\\Documents\\ML Seminar\\Deutscher Finanzmarkt Daten.xlsx")
DFM <- data.frame(X_bei = DFM.roh$s_bei, X_bayn = DFM.roh$s_bayn)

y_a <- ecdf(DFM$X_bei)(DFM$X_bei)
y_b <- ecdf(DFM$X_bayn)(DFM$X_bayn)
Datacop <- data.frame(y_a, y_b)

which(is.na(Datacop), arr.ind=TRUE)
#row col
all(sapply(Datacop, is.finite))
#TRUE
BiCopKDE(Datacop$y_a, Datacop$y_b, "surface")
# cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only
```

The dataset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzAi2.png)

Anybody with an idea to solve this?

Best,
Simon

Answer (score 1):

A good way to get what you want is to use `BiCopSelect`, which is a function in the `VineCopula` package. Once you get the result, then you can just use the plot function available in the same package.